# spring boot application does not start in STS; but builds fine in maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot.

I am trying to run a very basic spring-boot application "Hello World"

When I navigate to the `pom.xml` file and run `mvn clean install`, it builds 
fine and creates the jar file.

However when I try and run it in Eclipse, it hangs at this line:

```
Apr 22, 2017 11:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Apr 22, 2017 11:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
Apr 22, 2017 11:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

I had a lot of problems with SLF4J and since it was not compiling properly, 
I excluded it the dependency for logback-classic.

```
<exclusion>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Comment: So, is the application really not starting (is there an endpoint to check) or is it just not logging properly?

Comment: The fact that you need an exclusion is imho an indication that you have messes up your dependencies in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I tried to create a very basic spring-boot app in STS.  Eclipse  project maven project  (made sure that maven- achetype-quickstart 1,1) was selected --> created a new springbootProj. Added the two dependencies :  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Comment: It looks like a dependency issue.


I kept getting this error :  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

I looked at the sugegsted fix and it was suggested that I add another dependeny for any of the 4 jars slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar. The version of logback-classic.jar was creating issues. Now the application seems to start correctly.